# Implementing auto suggest backend in java, must be fast

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, search, autocomplete, trie

I want to build a servlet that gets a search string and returns all possible matches (just like Google search). However, in my case I don't have a lot of data - just about 100,000 strings to match against the query.
My questions is, what DB is recommended for that, what cache is needed for mininml response times?
By the way my client is GWT.

My general assumption is that some cache is needed - for example, reading all the data into the RAM instead of accessing the DB each time.
I need a fast response time - just like in Google search (in my case it's easier, I don't have too much information to index).

Comment: You'll probably want to use Apache Solr. See their edgeNGramFilter . PostgreSQL database support prefix wildcard full text search, which would be useful too

Comment: Thanks solr/lucene looks good. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache in the RAM for faster response time, I suggest try [Redis](http://www.redis.io). Redis has command ZRANGEBYLEX specifically for autocomplete. Its quite fast. They have put up a demo of it on http://autocomplete.redis.io/ (turned off right now).